# Command in MS Word on Mac to resize whole text

Tags: ms-office

A nice feature of TextEdit on a Mac is the Command+ or Command- shortcut which makes a selected piece of text grow
or shrink, respecting the ratios between the different parts of the text (thus, if a heading’s font size is twice that of a paragraph, this 2:1 ratio is preserved by Command+ or Command-).

I have been unable to find an equivalent in the MS Word 2011  on my Mac 10.11.6. Are there any ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in MS Word 11 using the Increase/Decrease Font Size buttons.

In MS Word select the Home tab. Under the section titled Font there are two buttons that both have an uppercase 'A' on them with an up and down arrow, respectively, next to the Font Size drop-down menu. If you select your entire document (using `Command-A`) and then select one of these buttons it will resize the entire documents proportionately.

The hot keys for these functions are `Shift-Command-<` and `Shift-Command->`. And again, you need to have the desired text highlighted in order for this to work.